# Dart null aware operator (??) not working when null value entered

Tags: dart

I've just started learning dart. I saw that I can use '??' to give a value if entered value is null.
But it isn't working as it should... I think.

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
 
    print("Enter a string");
    String input = stdin.readLineSync() ?? 'hello';
    print(input);
        
}
```

If I'm not wrong this should print 'hello' if the user doesn't enter anything.
But it just prints an empty line. I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: How do you enter the "null value"? By pressing enter?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `readLineSync` function returns `null` if no bytes preceded the end of input. Internally, the `readLineSync` function calls the `readByteSync` function. Which says:

"Synchronously reads a byte from stdin. This call will block until a byte is available. If at end of file, -1 is returned."

Since the input is read from `stdin`, you can trigger an EOF character by sending CTRL+Z (Windows) or CTRL+D (Linux) to your cmd/terminal, or by sending the characters to the stream itself (not sure how to do this in Dart).

---

When you press `Enter`, that inserts a CR/LF (depending on your OS) character into the input stream, which is then handled by the `readLineSync` method depending on its configuration and your current system.

Therefore, the return will not be null when you press enter. It will be the CR/LF character(s) if you set the `retainNewlines` parameter to true (which again, depends on your OS).

You can verify this by calling the following:

```
final value = stdin.readLineSync(retainNewlines: true); // press Enter/Return
print("read: ${value?.codeUnits.last}"); // prints 10 (LF) on Mac
```

Otherwise, it is `false`, and the actual return value of the function is will be determined by the `encoding.decode` method (defaults to `systemEncoder`). Either way, the encoding will be decoding an empty `List<int>` when you press Enter, and `retainNewLines` is `false`.

To account for all scenarios (null, CR/LF, value), you would write:

```
final input = stdin.readLineSync();

const CR = 13;
const LF = 10;

/// Handles different parameters that can be passed to readLinesSync
final value = switch (input) {
  null || CR || LF => "Empty",
  _ => input,
};
```

Comment: I dont think CR / LF check is necessary - `retainNewlines` is false by default. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html

Comment: @Lesiak I saw that, but the docs also say "Blocks until a full line is available." and "Lines may be terminated by either `<CR><LF>` or `<LF>`."... I suppose the correct interpretation is that the character is omitted, but the byte itself was read. The convert at the end of the source simply returns an empty String for an empty list of bytes.

Comment: Fortunately there is no need to guess, as the source code is available. If `retainNewlines` is false, the function may return a series of `CF`, but `LF` is never returned.

Comment: Also `the only way to trigger a EOF character is by CTRL+Z (Windows), CTRL+D (Linux), etc.` is not true - you seem to be considering only terminal input.

Comment: @offworldwelcome I tried your code. What is it supposed to print. Cause when i printed input and value, both were still just new lines.

Comment: @Rithwik It is printing a new line because the `print` function inserts a new line. The String returned from `readLineSync` is the empty string.

Comment: @Lesiak I've clarified. Let me know if you find any more inaccuracies on my part.

Comment: @offworldwelcome you can get empty input by using file or pipe as stdin. Anyway, I think your answer is complete enough, +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

```dart
print("Enter a string");
final String? input =  stdin.readLineSync() ?? 'hello';
print(input);
```

[image]